# How to use solana-wallet-adapter with metaplex-foundation/js

Tags: anchor, metaplex, solana-wallet-adapter

How to use a `wallet` with `metaplex-foundation/js` rather than `Keypair`?

This will give a compilation error

```
const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(
    keypairIdentity(wallet)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

using `walletAdapterIdentity` rather than `keypairIdentity` will solve this issue.

```
import { walletAdapterIdentity, Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js'

const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(
    walletAdapterIdentity(wallet)
)
```